# Software worked on Vista basic but does not install on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compatibility

I use some software called winspeakerz. I used to use it on Windows Vista Basic. Now I have a new laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium.

I was unable to install the software, as it shows `error "0"` during installation. I have contacted the software company, but I don't think they are interested in developing for Windows 7. Is there any way to get the software to install?

Answer (score 0):

[Error 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) generally means it installed successfully. If you are having issues after installation or could provide more information, I may be able to assist provided the additional info.

You may want to try using [compatibility settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Make-older-programs-run-in-this-version-of-Windows) if it is really a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the installer exe and select "run as administrator".

Comment: How is this supposed to help? A more detailed answer would be nice.

Comment: Some software needs to be installed with full administrator credentials, and no, user accounts do not have full admin rights.